# Unusual behavior with AcroPDF viewer

Tags: pdf, vb6, adobe, acrobat

I'm working on an old VB6 application and I'm trying to include a .pdf viewer in my application. Previously we were using .snp extensions, however, we decided to make a switch to PDF's since Win10 does not like .snp.

Anyway, I'm trying to have two controls in my form, 1 for snaps and 1 for pdf, so I'm using snap viewer, and AcroPDF viewer. The Component name I'm using for the AcroPDF is

> Adobe Acrobat 7.0 Browser Control Type Library 1.0

on Form_LOad i check for extension, and depending on what it is, that's the control i display.

Here's the interesting part - when I create an .exe and run it, it works like a charm, no issues whatsover. The weird behavior I get is when I run it out of IDE, regardless of whether I try to view the .pdf or .snp file, I get an empty message box. Also, if it happens to be a .pdf document, it doesn't display anything in the viewer, however, snaps work.

Here's the image of the message box...
[image]

I am not doing anything unusual with this... on form load, i simply check the extension and either make set it to Visible or not...For the directory, i do something like this..

```
pdfViewer.src = C://...directory
```

Like I said, this works fine when run out of .exe but gives me the message box when running out of IDE> Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF problem maybe because Adobe has migrate the library to 64bit, this break the compatibility with applications (written on any programming language that use this components).
A simply solution is to avoid to add the reference of Adobe library in your project (early-binding), and use instead on **late-binding** as explained on the below article (with sample project for VB6.0 and VB.NET) where you can load a PDF in Form or PictureBox:

**PDF in VBForm with no OCX/DLL (late binding)**

http://nuke.vbcorner.net/Articles/VB60/PDFinVBFormwithnoOCXDLLlatebinding/tabid/120/language/en-US/Default.aspx

Comment: Seems like good info but not sure if this explains the IDE vs. compiled differences the OP mentioned

Comment: YEs the issue is with running it out of IDE where i get the message box, it works fine from .exe. I've come across some articles where people were not able to use acroPDF with the 11.0.0.7 update of Adobe but in this case everything is working except for the IDE. So i'm not really sure what's going on.

Comment: And I guess I'm not really sure how I'd use this. If I want to use a PDFviewer in my form, how would I go about it with this - i removed the control and unchecked the reference and while this code compiles fine I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do other than adding the necessary code.

Comment: The above sample (late-bindind) work IN and OUT the VB6.0 IDE. Late-bindind ensure that your application are version indipendent (doesn't matter the Adobe version installed). 
Is this a problem for you?

Comment: Basically I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do. Am i supposed to uncheck the Adobe component? if i do that, then I can't see the AcroPDF component to add to my form. What am I exactly supposed to do with the code from the link?

Comment: I need to be able to have a component within my application to view the PDF. i think you mean just launching adobe acrobat outside the application. I need a component to be included in my form!